# Как сменить пути до файлов конфигурации CLion?

Tags: c++, intellij-idea, jetbrains, clion

Установил Clion, настроил окружение:

[image: Окружение в CLion]

Причем при установке, т.к. имя пользователя изначально было написано на кириллице, все файлы конфигурации положились по адресу c:\Users\Борис.clion10\ В пути, как видно, есть кириллица. Сменить этот путь никак не получилось (искал корни полнотекстовым поиском по файлам и в реестре...). Из-за кириллицы, при попытке собрать простеникий проект вылезают ошибки(там несколько, это только первое сообщение):

```
Error:The C compiler "C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x64-4.8.1-release-posix-seh-rev5/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.
It fails with the following output:
 Change Dir: C:/Users/Р‘РѕСЂРёСЃ/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/4406bad6/4406bad6/__default__/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build Command:"C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X64-48~1.1-R/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTryCompileExec242522220/fast"
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X64-48~1.1-R/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec242522220.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec242522220.dir/build
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Борис/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/4406bad6/4406bad6/__default__/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 1.0.4\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report C:\Users\Р‘РѕСЂРёСЃ\.clion10\system\cmake\generated\4406bad6\4406bad6\__default__\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec242522220.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
C:\PROGRA~1\MINGW-~1\X64-48~1.1-R\bin\gcc.exe -o CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec242522220.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -c C:\Users\Р‘РѕСЂРёСЃ\.clion10\system\cmake\generated\4406bad6\4406bad6\__default__\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c
gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Р‘РѕСЂРёСЃ\.clion10\system\cmake\generated\4406bad6\4406bad6\__default__\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec242522220.dir\build.make:56: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec242522220.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec242522220.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Борис/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/4406bad6/4406bad6/__default__/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:116: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec242522220/fast' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTryCompileExec242522220/fast] Error 2
CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
```

Из переменных, что вылезают во вкладке Cache есть только одна, которая содержит кириллицу(test_BINARY_DIR, где test это название проекта):

[image: переменная с кириллицей]

Попытка изменить эту переменную прямо из этого окошка не увенчались успехом... Изменить её из файла CMakeLists.txt c помощью строки:

set(test_BINARY_DIR C:/Users/MrBoriska/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/4406bad6/4406bad6/**default**)

так же не увенчалась успехом(C:/Users/MrBoriska это символическая ссылка на C:/Users/Борис)

Помогите, пожалуйста, а то уже теряю надежды...

Comment: из сообщения непонятно: в самой `.clion10` текстовые совпадения искали?

Comment: да, искал. Эх. а ведь я уже решил проблему. Ответить самому на свой вопрос? Это вообще законно тут?

Comment: да, вполне, можно еще и принять спустя N часов

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, хотел как лучше, а получилось как всегда. Решил проблему сам.

А решил чисто случайно... Решил поискать конфиги, думая может найду такой, где можно поменять адрес до этой .clion10 . В итоге нашел его тут: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 1.0.4\bin\idea.properties 
Там все предельно просто, сам конфиг задокументирован. Две строчки добавил:

```
idea.config.path=c:/JetBrains/.clion/config
idea.system.path=c:/JetBrains/.clion/system
```

Но вообще странно, что этот случай не извествен народу. Ситуация то довольно популярная должна быть. Кириллическое имя пользователя и это все условия.